# mybatis insertion to multiple tables

Tags: mybatis

I need to insert data to multiple tables using mybatis. For both tables pojo class are different and the insertion of first table(auto increment) id is input to the next table.My mapper is as below.Can you help me proceed further.

I am getting below mentioned error.

The content of element type

> "foreach" must match "(include|trim|where|set|foreach|choose|if|bind)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through multiple seperated dao interfaces within a single one transaction.

Each previous return value is the input of next one.